# Can you update the Extra data fields of a physical beacon using AltBeacon/Android Beacon libary?

Tags: android, ibeacon, beacon, altbeacon

I'm trying to see if I can use the Android beacon library to set Data Fields on a physical beacon.  The function `setExtraDataFields` exists, and if i call that on a `Beacon` object and immediately call `getExtraDataFields`, the object itself has changed but on the next ranging when I pickup the beacon signal, `getExtraDataFields` remains unchanged. Is there some "force" or "update" function I need to call to enact/save the changes? I feel like something like this is possible because the Location app attempts to change the RSSI of a device I believe, but all the code examples I have found thus far are for using the Android device as a simulated beacon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use the Android Beacon Library to modify the values of a hardware beacon.  The values returned by getExtraDataFields are effectively read-only.

Two reasons why:

1. Bluetooth beacons are one-way transmitters that send a unique identifier and associated data.  They do not receive data, and cannot be remotely updated over the same channel.
2. Some beacon hardware manufacturers do have proprietary extensions allowing an external app to use a Bluetooth service to configure the beacon's identifiers and data fields.  But the mechanism  to do so is different for every manufacturer.  It is not possible for the Android Beacon Library to even figure out which manufacturer made each beacon it sees, let alone use their proprietary SDK or service to update the fields.

Bottom line: If you want to update the fields from your app, you need to ask your hardware manufacturer to give you instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough, helpful, and quick response! I'm getting my hands on a Kontakt beacon this weekend, and I know their mobile app allows for configuring of some settings so I'm hoping their SDK will as well.